# export csv file and get <br> as &lt;br&gt;

Tags: php, html

I want to export csv after fetch data from table but after open csv file I get

```
<br> tag as &gt;br&gt;
```

I want this as

```
<br>.
```

How to get it. Please help me if anyone have a solution

Comment: Please post the code you use to export the CSV data. Without this its pretty impossible for us to help you. And what are the <br> tags ment for. Do you want them to make new lines in you csv file, or are the csv-file supposed to contain html code?

Comment: Not enough information provided.  Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code always.
But this can solve your problem but its not a nice soluition but I cant provide more without your code.

```
str_replace("&gt;br&gt;","<br>",your_text);
```